# Como não deixar aparecer um Dominio no Google e outros buscadores

Tags: php, html, segurança, google

Tenho um sistema online e não gostaria que meu domínio aparece-se no google ou outros buscadores, gostaria de torna-lo privado. existe alguma forma de fazer isso?